# Is Highmaps included in the .NET wrapper?

Tags: highcharts, maps, dotnethighcharts

We have successfully been using the Highcharts .NET wrapper to create maps on our analytics project. However, now I come to create a map chart I can't find any of the Highmaps objects in the wrapper? Can someone point out where they are for me please or let me know if there is no .NET wrapper for Highmaps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can find out more about what is supported and what is not:
https://www.highcharts.com/wrappers/

Currently, .Net wrapper does not contain maps.